# How to search for data in many tables?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, search, typeorm

How to search data in all tables from my database? I need to create some sort of search like is on Github where after entering the phrase into the search engine, it looks for us both repositories, issues and users, I need to do something like this but with searching in entities like: `User`, `Order` and `Projects`,

I'm using `TypeORM` and simple search query looks like below:

```
const data = await this.conn
      .getRepository(Order)
      .createQueryBuilder('order')
      .where('order.name = :name ', { name : name })
      .leftJoin('order.author', 'author')
      .orderBy('order.lastUpdate', 'DESC');
```

but how to search not only in `Order` entity but also in other tables like `User` and `Projects`? How the biggest company search engine works?

Answer (score 0):

Big companies such as google base their technologies on AI now, using them as a system to organise Big Data ([see more on that here](https://neilpatel.com/blog/how-google-search-engine-really-works/)). However, google originally used the Page Rank algorithm that would assign higher values to websites that had high referral rates from other sites ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)).

It sounds like what you would get the most from is the `LIKE` keyword ([see the basics](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)) in combination with the `UNION` keyword ([info here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)).

You could probably get some good results with something like this in SQL (I dont know TypeORM):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%searchterm%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE name LIKE '%searchterm%';
```